# Why does re-opening the data source of a connection pull throws SQL Exception?

Tags: java, swing, connection-pooling

In java, I'm using the hikari connection pool to handle the data exchange between the app and the database.
When I return from the main window to the login window, I close the datasource. After that, if I trying to connect again(switch from login window to main window), I'm getting a nullpointerexception and a SQL exception.
Here is relevant bits of code
Login frame:

```
Boolean connected = DatabaseHandler.checkCredentials(host, database, username, password);
```

DatabaseHandler checkCredentials method:

```
public static boolean checkCredentials(String host, String database, String user, String password){
    hkHost = host;
    hkDatabase = database;
    hkUser = user;
    hkPassword = password;

    try {
        getDataSource();
        return true;
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Could not get the data source with those credentials");
        return false;
    }
}
```

GetDataSource method:

```
public static HikariDataSource getDataSource(){
            if(dataSource == null){
                HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
                config.setMaximumPoolSize(100);
                config.setDataSourceClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource");
                config.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", (Object)hkHost);
                config.addDataSourceProperty("port", (Object)"3306");
                config.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", (Object)hkDatabase);
                config.addDataSourceProperty("user", (Object)hkUser);
                config.addDataSourceProperty("password", (Object)hkPassword);
                dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
            }
            return dataSource;
        }
```

Closing the datasource when returning to the login frame.

```
dataSource.close();
```

> java.sql.SQLException: HikariDataSource HikariDataSource
>   (HikariPool-1) has been closed.   at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:81)
>     at DatabaseHandler.getMetaData(DatabaseHandler.java:150)    at
>   DatabaseOperations.getAllTables(DatabaseOperations.java:31)   at
>   ApplicationWindow.setTablesList(ApplicationWindow.java:100)   at
>   ApplicationWindow.(ApplicationWindow.java:71)   at
>   LoginWindow$1.actionPerformed(LoginWindow.java:301)   at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) Exception in thread
>   "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   DatabaseHandler.getMetaData(DatabaseHandler.java:160)     at
>   DatabaseOperations.getAllTables(DatabaseOperations.java:31)   at
>   ApplicationWindow.setTablesList(ApplicationWindow.java:100)   at
>   ApplicationWindow.(ApplicationWindow.java:71)   at
>   LoginWindow$1.actionPerformed(LoginWindow.java:301)   at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Edit: I found the solution. In the getDataSource method, I was checking if the dataSource is null and only then creating a new dataSource, but after closing the dataSource, it is no longer null. I changed `

```
if(dataSource == null)<br/><br/>
```

to

```
if(dataSource == null || dataSource.isClosed())`
```

Comment: Well, you close the datasource, and then try getting connections out of it, hence the error. What do you expect? And why do you close the datasource? And why does a Swing application need a pool of 100 database connections?

Comment: @JBNizet it is a database management tool, hence the connections... In the login window, when calling the checkCredentials method which in turn calls the getDataSource method it is supposed to set the credentials for the pool and then get a new datasource so I don't understand why it is attempting to get connections on the closed datasource instead of creating a new one as intended.

Comment: Well, just read your code: it creates a datasource only if it's not null. Once created, it always returns the same dataSource. unless of course you reset it to null, but you don't seem to do that.

Comment: I actually found this just a few minutes ago and it works like charm now, thanks for taking the time with me.